# How to increase the data node for elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a cluster and I didn't do any setting to add new nodes to share the load balance activity. Like I want to create 4 nodes and It needs to share the data based on load and keep the data persist with local drive so that the data won't be lost even If I restarted the docker.

[image]

I'm not sure How can I increase the data nodes and achieve the load balancing.

Can anyone help me here to add new data nodes and persist the records in fs.

Note: Kibana is installed as docker image (Dockers-ELK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, then you need to make sure the data is persisted and kept safe for in case of docker restart.

For the same, what my team is doing is:

- First we added the SSDs to the data node where SSDs are attached to the every elastic nodes. SSDs are mounted to the docker nodes
- Replication is enabled and we made the elastic deployment to replicate the data atleast on 2 more nodes. By doing this we are assuring that the data is safe for 2 node level failure. You can increase this based on the how data is critical for you

Kibana saves it data on elastic search index which will be covered by the replication setup you will do on the elastic search nodes. We have put multiple kibana nodes behind load balancer to share load.

To add more nodes you need to setup the elastic search cluster with master and data node setup to be zone aware. You can follow this [Elastic Blog](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/add-elasticsearch-nodes.html)